# Why "plot" doesn't display the line?

Tags: r, plot

I have this plot that it's creating me some problems as I don't manage to plot the red line between CIs. This plot is the fifth of a series of plots that are identical in nature and code. Only in this case, the line doesn't show up. I can't figure it out why.

This is my dataset and code:

```
ap_pp = structure(list(appp = c(0.0534256470459521, 0.318338283911788, 
0.510498594892796, 0.659918013907143, 0.847855923395071, 1.33512933449448, 
1.79114871626335), LB_T = c(-0.0039953960988687, -0.00128119112255898, 
1.231602663197e-05, 0.000409544070864543, 0.00117091129359269, 
0.00719127778296817, 0.0141800410470155), UB_T = c(0.00506390903978775, 
0.00764795680079474, 0.010197655871224, 0.0127888162072783, 0.0157862071743087, 
0.0195113089069214, 0.0216429332782514), LB_T = c(-0.0039953960988687, 
-0.00128119112255898, 1.231602663197e-05, 0.000409544070864543, 
0.00117091129359269, 0.00719127778296817, 0.0141800410470155), 
    UB_T = c(0.00506390903978775, 0.00764795680079474, 0.010197655871224, 
    0.0127888162072783, 0.0157862071743087, 0.0195113089069214, 
    0.0216429332782514)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L)) 
  plot(ap_pp$appp, ylim = range(c(ap_pp$LB_T, appp$UB_T)), xlab = "", ylab = "", main = "LSAP", type = "n", xaxt = "n")

axis(1, at = 1:7, labels = load_unscaled_m$Date)

with(ap_pp, polygon(c(xx,rev(xx)),c(LB_T,rev(UB_T)), col = "#FFA6AA", border = FALSE))
 abline(h = 0, col = "black", lty = 2)
  lines(ap_pp$appp, type = "o", lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues:

1. Typo, you use `appp$UB_T` in the `range()`, which doesn't exist. You need `ap_pp$UB_T`
2. Range. The line data you are trying to plot has a minimum of 0.05:

```
range(ap_pp$appp)
[1] 0.05342565 1.79114872
```

However, you set the y-axis to have a maximum of 0.02:

```
range(c(ap_pp$LB_T, ap_pp$UB_T))
[1] -0.003995396  0.021642933
```

Since the maximum of your `y` axis, 0.0216, is less than the minimum of the data you are plotting, 0.0534, all the points you are trying to plot are "above" the graph.

3. Graph type. You say "line", but by default `plot` will plot points. If you want a line, use `type = "l"`. (Or `lines()`, as you do later.)
4. I have no idea what `xx` is, so I don't know what's going on with your polygon code. But presumably the y limits are again defined by `UB_T` and `LB_T`, and so the maximum of the y axis is still lower than the minimum of the data in `lines()`
5. Duplicate column names are a bad idea. You have two columns named `LB_T` and two named `UB_T`. They appear to be identical, which is less bad than if they were different, but I would strongly suggest not using duplicate column names so there is no ambiguity about which column you are referring to.

Perhaps you should include `ap_pp$ppp` in the `range` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was driving me crazy! Thanks!